# Can you explain why Google Closure Templates uses so many pointless intermediate objects?

Tags: java

Ladies, gentlemen.

I was reading [Google's documentation for Closure Templates.](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_java)

There's not that much code in there, but it represents what I'm having trouble understanding (in Java, in particular). I'll go line by line:

```
// Bundle the Soy files for your project into a SoyFileSet.
SoyFileSet sfs = new SoyFileSet.Builder().add(new File("simple.soy")).build();
```

I get this. An object to gather multiple template files. Fine. But why the `.Builder()`? Why not just `new SoyFileSet().add(...).build()`?

```
// Compile the template into a SoyTofu object.
// SoyTofu's newRenderer method returns an object that can render any template in file set.
SoyTofu tofu = sfs.compileToJavaObj();
```

Fine. But why do I want this? After I have the files gathered, I was expecting just something like `sfs.render(Map<> data)`. Why do I need to compile this to a Java object?

And finally...

```
// Call the template with no data.
System.out.println(tofu.newRenderer("examples.simple.helloWorld").render());
```

Great, why do I have to create an intermediate object just so I can call a method od it? Why couldn't the `sfs` object have a `.render()` method? Why do I need a `Renderer` object?

Java is frustrating, why aren't things done in a straightforward way?

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot. Give me a second.

Comment: This is a very vague and general question, which isn't really fit for SO.

Comment: It isn't Java that is frustrating for you in this case. The Closure Templates API might be. And you need `new SoyFileSet.Builder()` because [`Builder` is an internal class of `SoyFileSet`](http://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/template/soy/SoyFileSet.java#104).

Comment: Also, when you ask Java experts for help, it's not a good idea to insult their language (referring to the words _pointless_ and _frustrating_ in your post).

Comment: @iWerner no. The objects seem pointless, as they exist for ONE line of code. Frustration is what I'm feeling. As long as I'm not insulting PEOPLE, I see no problem. You are not your code, you are not your programming language.

Comment: @user1520653: Name *one* question about a missing semicolon that people like. You seem to make a lot of statements without any justification. Also, who said that SO is tolerant towards new users?

Comment: Try rewriting your question to be more specific. `A more straight-forward way` for example, is a very subjective opinion, and is difficult to answer. Also, don't ask several questions in one post.

Comment: By the way, your "suggestions" make very little sense from an API design point of view. Why would a `SoyFileSet` object have a `build()` method, for example? Misusing the class as a builder violates the single responsibility principle. The other two points you address are for performance reasons. You should reuse those instance, rather than creating them for only a single line of code.

Comment: @user1520653 well, you're slowly starting to insult people ("I've noticed you prefer questions about missing semicolons.") Please calm down and ask constructive questions. And as already said, it's not the language that makes this example complex but the framework and the API the developers chose. They certainly have their reasons for this and if you don't agree, then you have a few options: discuss with the framework developers, learn to live with it or don't use it.

Comment: Out of interest: what languages did you use so far? For what type of applications? What's your general experience in programming? And finally, why are you starting to use Java if it you get frustrated with it?

Comment: Object allocation and GC is super-cheap in Java, so API authors tend to focus on modularity and good design principles over small performance optimizations that end up costing performance in the long term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `SoyFileset` is probably an immutable object so you use a `Builder` to build it in one step. BTW your "why not" counterexample doesn't make much sense since it also ends with `build`. In your case no `build` would be required.
2. `SoyTofu` is a heavyweight factory object that costs time and space to produce. You want to reuse it many times to produce renderers. That's why you create it in a separate step, and then keep it.
3. You need a `newRenderer` because rendering is a complex process that involves quite a bit of internal state. The `Renderer` object's instance variables is where that state is being kept as the program flow meanders through its methods. You'll also probably get some lifecycle/state methods on the renderer, maybe to see how the rendering went, or maybe to give some additional info/config before rendering.

This is an example of the classic pattern where we divide the work between a pre-built heavy, immutable, thread-safe, long-lived factory object and leightweight, non-thread-safe, mutable, disposable objects that share the immutable state of their factory to do one task in a single thread and are then thrown away.

In conclusion: these are all signs of a well-engineered, industry-strength API. Java doesn't by necessity look like that, but if you went for the straightforward approach, you'd shoot yourself in the foot performance-wise, or even run out of memory.

Answer (score 6):

The `Builder`, `Factory` and similarly named methods are used as part of the [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). This is useful when the creation of objects needs to be centralized for some reason. For example, the factory might be internally keeping a pool of objects for efficiency reasons and not returning a new instance every time.

Comment: In this case, I doubt it. There is no pool of renderers in there.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: It was just a usage example, I'm not sure if it applies in this case. Anyway, the rant seems to be about java in general.